# For POST actions use HtmlHelper extension method Html.Kentico().PageData() to persist the page context

Tags: kentico, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

Hi Please assist I am building .net core site with kentico 13. I am getting this error below
Missing page context data. If required use IPageDataContextInitializer.Initialize method to initialize the context manually. For POST actions use HtmlHelper extension method Html.Kentico().PageData() to persist the page context